# Past Perfect Negative Plus Future Perfect while in the Present

Tags: grammar, conditionals, conditional-perfect, conditional-future

Given the situation:

- I enjoy a podcast that has ended
- There is a bonus episode of the podcast that I am not aware of that, if I were aware, I would listen to it
- Somebody tells me about the existence of the episode

The best way I can think to write this, that isn't super cumbersome, is to say:

"If you hadn't told me about that episode, I never would have"

But the "never would have" part implies that I have already listened to it.

"If you hadn't told me about that episode, I will have never listened to it"

While this gets closer what a theoretical future me would not have done, it makes it seem like I'm not planning on listening to it.

Is there a better way to phrase this that I'm missing?

Comment: This works whether you subsequently heard the episode or not: *If you hadn't told me about that episode, I would have never known about it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for the impossible. ("Past Perfect Negative Plus Future Perfect while in the Present")

The future perfect is not combined with a past tense verb in the 'if-clause'. This is because, by default, the past tense in the if-clause represents a past conditional and the future perfect in the result clause represents the non-past (present or future). It's also impossible because you are apparently trying you combine a real conditional (you did tell me about it) with what you call 'a theoretical future me', which calls for an unreal conditional. You can't have it both ways.

If you want something that works your can use

> If you hadn't've (had not have) told me about it, I wouldn't have known about it.

This doesn't imply you're going to listen to the bonus episode.

Comment: I think this gives the reasoning as to why the statement I want isn't possible. It does feel odd though that I can say "If you hadn't told me, I wouldn't have listened to it" after I have listened to it. But, if I'm at a different point in time, I have to make two different thoughts/sentences to convey the same meaning. But also it's probably a rare enough occasion that the language doesn't need another tense.